# My nav stopped working - CSS mods and JQuery error

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, navigation, media-queries

So I'm modifying the WooThemes Function theme using a child theme setup.

I wanted to modify how the top nav and main nav appeared at different scren widths, so did some modifying of the CSS. I thought it was all fine, except now the nav doesn't open when the screen width is between 480px and 767px. I narrowed it down to the CSS definition which seems to have caused it, but there also seems to be a JQuery error - and I have no idea about JQuery.

Here is the page: http://dev.thecyclery.net.au/function-nav/

Here is the CSS mods I have made to adjust the nav appearances, with a comment next to the offending statement:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
/* upto 767px */

 /*TOP MENU - disabling dropdown, making fullscreen top nav remain in place. Font size increases on smaller screens.
---------*/

#wrapper #top select.mobileMenu {
    display: none !important;
}

#top {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    padding: 0 1.618em;
}

.fix:before, .fix:after, .col-full:before, .col-full:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fix:after, .col-full:after {
    clear: both;
}

.fix:before, .fix:after, .col-full:before, .col-full:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main.fullwidth, .layout-full #main, .col-full {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 75.998em;
    width: 100%;
}

/*If this following statement is commented out, the main nav starts working again, but the top nav disaapears...*/
div#top ul#top-nav {
    display: block;
}



#top ul.nav {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

ul.nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.fl {
    float: left;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

ul.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
}
#text-2 div, ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#top ul.nav > li a {
    color: #999999;
}

#top ul.nav > li a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.53em 1em;
    font-size: 120%;
}

#top ul.nav > li.current_page_item a, #top ul.nav > li.current_page_parent a, #top ul.nav > li.current-menu-ancestor a, #top ul.nav > li.current-cat a, #top ul.nav > li.li.current-menu-item a, #top ul.nav > li.current-post-ancestor a, #top ul.nav > li.current-menu-parent a, #top ul.nav > li.current-post-parent a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #52A0CD;
}
```

The JQuery error I get is as follows:
    TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this up, I'd be mighty grateful!

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: which jquery version you are using ? try using latest one.

Comment: Not sure how you added jquery in your code. Use cdn path like "<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>"

Comment: As I mentioned, I have no idea about the JQuery - it's obviously built into the theme somehow. The only reason I found it was through the Firebug error console... so @Suresh Ponnukalai I'm not sure how to change the script...